# Location Auto Suggest Sample iOS

Tags: ios, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I'm working on iOS application that has a location suggest feature.
I want to implement auto location suggest, but I can't find a good sample for this.

I want to find out coordinate data from location name.

Please let me know if someone have good example for me.
I've looked at https://github.com/spoletto/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete but sometimes it does not support nearest locations when i type address on textfield.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `CLGeoCoder` class may help you here - https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH4-SW8

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paul. I would be happy if you can help me for more details. well, i want one more feature in my app and that is when i type a address to textfield, it should suggest a number of places. My question is out of range a little. thanks again.

Comment: hi Paul, can you please answer my question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840556/google-place-api-search-result-with-place-id-returns-different-location-with-pla
I would be happy if you can help me. thanks.